# Movie player in new view controller does not play movie from dynamic url iPhone iOS

Tags: iphone, xml, ios, uitableview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a project with UITableView that is filled with data about movies parsed from XML. When I press on row new view controller is displayed. I have assigned all properties to receive information in new view controller such as: title, description and url string to the movie. It looks to be fine when I NSLog those values. But the clue of this new view controller is to display automatically movie from specific url. Below there is code that I use.

```
videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

urlString is my adress for movie from XML

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)  name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:videoPlayer];

videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
[self.view addSubview:videoPlayer.view];
videoPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 300);  
[videoPlayer play];
```

If there is statically assigned url string like this

```
NSString *url = @"http://www.myserv.com/video.mp4";

videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
```

everything works. If anyone have an idea how to solve my problem I would be grateful.

Comment: Add some debug-logging to the URL - that is, add a `NSLog(@"the URL: %@", urlString);` just before that `videoUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];`

Comment: I have done that. NSLog for "the url" is the correct string to the destination of the movie. But after `NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString ]`; I am checking log and the value for videoURL is `(null)`.

Comment: So that indicates that the urlString is not convertible into a proper NSURL -> your string is possible escaped incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the following method to strings before turning them into URLs

```
- (NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

Comment: In the end it turned out that your tip was helpful. Thanks!